# How to fix missing folder "cypress" as installing Cypress v6.6 with nodejs 14

Tags: nodes, cypress, npm-install

I tried with both Nodejs v14 and v12. As installing Cypress v6.6 with command line

> npm install cypress --save-dev

The project doesn't have "cypress" folder. It also has folder "node_modules" and file package-lock.json
I cleared cache Cypress folder but it also doesn't work. Could anyone help me fix this issue?

Answer (score 1):

- `yarn add cypress@latest --dev` (should add cypress to package.json)
- `npx cypress open` at the first run should generate `cypress` folder and open cypress UI runner.

official [docs](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/getting-started/installing-cypress.html)